# How to only show an image stored in S3 bucket to anyone with the right key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My use case is very simple: I have images that I want to display only to people that can prove they are supposed to be able to see them.

I authenticate the users privately on my own server, using my own methods. However, just granting them access to an image is no good, because if the image is hosted publicly anyone with minor "hacking" skills can find it. If I can add like "?key=fdsfsdhfsdhfsdhf" to the image, that would be enough for me. I do NOT want to have to deal with APIs and IAMs (whatever that is) and other bullshit.

S3 bucket policies and encryption and everything are a giant mess, so I get no help from their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The correct method would be:

- Keep the objects private in Amazon S3
- Users authenticate to your back-end
- When a user requests access to an object, the code in your back-end determines whether they are allowed to access the object
- If so, your back-end generates an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object
- The pre-signed URL can be returned directly, or included in an HTML page (eg `<img src='...'>`)
- When the user's browser requests that object from Amazon S3, the pre-signed URL will be verified to confirm that it has been correctly signed and is still within the expiry period. If so, S3 will serve the object to the user.

The nice part of this approach is that your back-end code has full control over whether a user can access an object. Generating the pre-signed URL can be done in just a couple of lines of code and does not require an API call to S3. However, **the pre-signed URL will need to be generated using an Access Key & Secret Key that has permission to access the private object**.

Comment: Requires API calls, sadly. That's a workload of a month or so just to install. Don't know why you say it doesn't need an API call then literally in the next sentence say it does.

Comment: Generating the pre-signed URL does not require an API call. However, the pre-signed URL includes a hash that is generated from a Secret Key that is associated with IAM credentials. This is how Amazon S3 knows that you are an authorized user who is permitted to grant access to the private object. If you do not use any IAM credentials, then there is no way for S3 to recognize your program as authorized to grant access.